# xsd conditional choice issue with the choice tag

Tags: xml, xsd

My Goal: I need to create a XSD file for a xml file. If the parent element is populated with "Yes" I want the child fields to be populated as well. If it is populated as "No" the child fields do not need populated. I am getting the error "Element is not supported in this context" for the first `<xs:choice>` tag.

See below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="hcns" xmlns:hc="hcns"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
 <xs:element name="HC">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="datacollection">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="dataitem"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>


                <xs:element name="Indicator" type ="Indicator_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4" nillable="false">
                  <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="Yes" type="YesType"/>
                    <xs:element name="No" type="NoType"/>
                  </xs:choice>
                  <xs:complexType name="YesType">
                    <xs:all>
                      <xs:element name="YesElemet1" type="YesElemet1Type" />
                      <xs:element name="YesElemet2" type="YesElemet2Type" />
                    </xs:all>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please show a complete XML Schema, together with XML samples that should be valid (or invalid, respectively) against your schema. What version of XML Schema do you use? Can you use Schematron?

Comment: Added the rest of the XSD code

Comment: Now that you have added some more XSD code: in your explanation, you are talking of "parent element" and "child field" - but we do not know what they correspond to in the XML schema. Also, again, please show an XML document that should be valid against your schema, and another that should be invalid.